# Combine jUnit timeout with @DirtiesContext

Tags: java, junit, spring-test

I have a testcase that modifies my spring context and might run into an infinite loop. After the testcase I'd like to have a clean spring context so I use the the `@DirtiesContext` annotation. In case of the infinite loop I added a jUnit timeout.

```
@Test(timeout = 1000)
@DirtiesContext
public void testTimeout() {
    //test stuff
}
```

The problem is that if the test runs into the timeout, jUnit seems to terminate it in a way that spring doesn't handle the context reset anymore. Same behaviour if I add `@DirtiesContext` on class level.

Is there another way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To configure a *timeout* with JUnit and the *Spring TestContext Framework* (TCF), you have two main categories of options:

1. **preemptive**: If you use JUnit's `Timeout` rule or the `timeout` attribute of `@Test`, your test and all nested rules, associated *before*/*after* methods, TCF callbacks, etc. will execute in a separate thread that is preemptively aborted if the *timeout* is exceeded.
2. **non-preemptive**: If you use Spring's `@Timed` annotation with the TCF, your test and all nested rules, associated *before*/*after* methods, TCF callbacks, etc. will execute in the same thread as the test runner, and the test will only fail if it terminates normally and the *timeout* has been exceeded.

Both the `Timeout` rule and the `timeout` attribute of `@Test` result in a `FailOnTimeout` statement being used under the hood; and `FailOnTimeout` executes the next statement in the chain within a separate thread which is preemptively terminated if the timeout is exceeded. Thus, the behavior for both of these JUnit-based configuration options would naturally be identical: execution of the statement chain ends prematurely without giving any *after* callbacks a chance to perform their tasks. The result is that the *afterTestMethod()* callback in Spring's `DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener` is never invoked in such scenarios, and consequently the context would not be *dirtied*.

> Is there another way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

For starters, using Spring's `@Timed` annotation is not an option for you since it will not preemptively abort code that runs in an infinite loop.

You mentioned that you discovered a work-around by using the  `@DirtiesContext(methodMode = BEFORE_METHOD)` feature introduced in Spring Framework 4.2. That *may* work in certain circumstances, but this work-around is fragile at best: using this work-around results in the context being closed and restarted *before* **this** particular method; however, if the code in question modifies the context before the preemptive timeout, your Spring context will remain corrupt for subsequent test methods.

The only *real* solution is to ensure that you use `@DirtiesContext` with the `BEFORE_METHOD` mode on the **next** method that executes *after* the method that was preemptively aborted due to a timeout. However... knowing exactly which method is the "next" method might be the challenging part... unless you use JUnit's `@FixMethodOrder` support.

Regards,

Sam (*author of the Spring TestContext Framework*)

Comment: Thanks for this great explanation. It was clear to me the `BEFORE_METHOD` statement had actually to be on the next method. I solved this by using this on any method in the class (there was only one that didn't need a timeout). What I forgot is that the next test class would run into a problem, so fragile indeed. I'm now thinking of "ignoring" the problem and just letting subsequent tests fail because of a dirty context in case of timeout and using `AFTER_METHOD` again. Since the endless loop should not occur once that bug is fixed. Anyway I think it doesn't get any better than your answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to work around my problem. I upgraded spring to 4.2.0 which is out for about a week and it supports cleaning context before a method.

```
@Test(timeout = 1000)
@DirtiesContext(methodMode = MethodMode.BEFORE_METHOD)
public void testTimeout() {
    //test stuff
}
```

This way the test still terminates after the timeout but the context is cleaned before the next method. Guess this way I have one unnecessary context initialization per test class but it works.